# React updates the state but not the component with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a blog application that I want to sort my posts by **votes** or **title**, so I have this buttons for sorting:

```
<Button size='mini' onClick={() => {this.props.sortByVotes()}}>
    Votes
</Button>
<Button size='mini' onClick={() => {this.props.sortByTitle()}}>
    Title
</Button>
```

The actions is like this:

```
export const sortByVotes = posts => ({ type: SORT_BY_VOTES })

export const sortByTitle = posts => ({ type: SORT_BY_TITLE })
```

And reducer is as it follows:

```
case SORT_BY_VOTES:
    return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.sort((a, b) => b.voteScore - a.voteScore)
    }
case SORT_BY_TITLE:
    return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.title > b.title) return 1
            if (a.title < b.title)return -1
            return 0
        })
    }
```

Finally, in the Main.js view I get posts in componentDidMount and shows it like this:

```
<Item.Group divided>
    {this.props.posts.map((p, idx) =>
        <PostSmall key={idx}
            id={p.id}
            title={p.title}
            body={p.body}
            category={p.category}
            voteScore={p.voteScore}
        />
    )}
</Item.Group>
```

Still in Main.js, I map the **posts** from **state** like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        posts: state.posts.posts,
        categories: state.categories.categories
    }
}
```

As you can see, nothing special here.

The problem is: the state is update as expected, but view not.

Ti'll now I have not figured out how to solve it, and why this is happening.

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Can you please share how you have bind the Redux state with the view part. I think the problem is with binding approach.

Comment: I think what you are asking is the last two snippets, they are in the main, view.. when the main view is mounted, I call `this.props.getPosts()`, and in mapDispatchToProps I have this: ```getPosts: () => dispatch(fetchPosts())```

Comment: Is it possible to share the entire code is codesandbox and share the link? I can refactor the code.

Comment: github can handle it? https://github.com/tomrlh/redux-reading

Comment: You have connected the components to the redux state, which is not recommended. Components should be pure and views should only connected to redux state.  Can you please remove the connect from components and pass the methods as props to components and try

Comment: don't use an `index` integer as a key. thats probably your problem. Change `<PostSmall key={idx}` to `<PostSmall key={p.id}`. Also in your reducer, change `state.posts.sort(...)` to `[...state.posts].sort(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The object posts is not changing hence React is not rendering the component.

I have added a work around fix.

reducers/posts.js

```js
case SORT_BY_VOTES:
   const posts = Object.assign({},{posts:state.posts.sort((a, b) => b.voteScore - a.voteScore
   )})
   return Object.assign ({}, state, posts);
```

In Main.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Container, Divider, Grid, Item } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Categories from '../components/Categories'
import PostSmall from '../components/PostSmall'
import PostsSorter from '../components/PostsSorter'

import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/posts'
import { fetchCategories } from '../actions/categories'

class Main extends React.Component {

 render() {
  const posts = this.props.posts ? this.props.posts.posts || [] : [];
  console.log('render')
  return (
   <Container>
    <Grid columns='equal'>
     <Grid.Column>
      <PostsSorter/>
      <Divider/>
      <Categories categories={this.props.categories}/>
     </Grid.Column>
     <Grid.Column width={10}>
      <Item.Group divided>
       {posts.map((p, idx) =>
        <PostSmall key={idx} post={p}/>
       )}
      </Item.Group>
     </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
   </Container>
  );
 }



 componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getPosts()
  this.props.getCategories()
 }
}



Main.propTypes = {
 posts: PropTypes.array,
 categories: PropTypes.array
}

Main.defaultProps = {
 posts: [],
 categories: []
}



function mapStateToProps(state) {
 console.log(state);
 return {
  posts: state.posts,
  categories: state.categories.categories
 }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return {
  getPosts: () => dispatch(fetchPosts()),
  getCategories: () => dispatch(fetchCategories())
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)
```

But you have to refactor the code in order to make the component pure and connect the redux state only to view.

Answer (score 0):

Your action doesnt send a payload. Are you initiating an API call in actions to send to the reducer? In your reducer, you need to capture the payload from actions and then update the state.

Actions: [actions.tsx](https://github.com/a2441918/augur-project/blob/'redux'/src/actions/actions.tsx)
Reducers: [reducers.tsx](https://github.com/a2441918/augur-project/blob/'redux'/src/reducers/ChangeAccountInputReducer.tsx)

So, the common workflow is to have a parameter in actions and then modify the default state in the reducer. See a sample above for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In this case the action type define which operation to perform: if sortByVotes() is dispatched, it will order by votes in descending order, without a payload saying { "byVotes": true} or something else.

Comment: What does console.log(state) in mapStateToProps give you?

Comment: I have not debugged this before.. it gives me the correct state, as it should be, sorted accordingly the sorting method chosen. But the props are not passed to child (re-rendered).

Comment: Then I would advise you to check the nextProps in componentWillReceiveProps() method. If nextProps has data, then use that to populate.

Comment: But why React don't check it by itself? This is intriguing me, cause the default behavior is rerender when it have new props, and sadly this lifecycle method is deprecated (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

Comment: Well, you have the answer. Do the check in componentDidUpdate(). Console.log both nextProps and this.props to get the difference.